# Dockerize a simple Vanilla Javascript Application

Tags: javascript, angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a simple javascript application `index.html`, `index.css`, a folder called `photos` and `index.js`. I don't have any node modules or config file.

I am trying to dockerize by app by creating a `dockerfile` and `docker-build.sh` file. I have searched online, but i keep seeing dockerfiles with nodejs examples. Any guide on how I can dockerize a simple vanilla js app?

Here's what I have, but it currently gets stock at `Attaching to display-ui`

`dockerfile`

```
# pull a nginx image
FROM nginx:alpine

ARG UID=101

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add bash \
    && apk add jq \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

    # Set working directory to nginx asset directory
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
# Remove default nginx static assets
RUN rm -rf ./*

# Copy assets over so Nginx can properly serve 
COPY apps/explorer.css .
COPY apps/explorer.js .
COPY apps/index.html .


RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html
# implement changes required to run NGINX as an unprivileged user
RUN sed -i 's,listen       80;,listen       8080;,' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
    && sed -i '/user  nginx;/d' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    && sed -i 's,/var/run/nginx.pid,/tmp/nginx.pid,' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    && sed -i "/^http {/a \    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;\n    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;\n    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;\n    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;\n    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;\n" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    # nginx user must own the cache and etc directory to write cache and tweak the nginx config
    && chown -R $UID:0 /var/cache/nginx \
    && chmod -R g+w /var/cache/nginx \
    && chown -R $UID:0 /etc/nginx \
    && chmod -R g+w /etc/nginx


EXPOSE 8080

USER nginx

# Containers run nginx with global directives and daemon off
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  s3-ui:
    container_name: display-ui
    image: display-ui:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      APP_ADDR: ":8080"
      MONITOR_ADDR: ":3090"
```

To run, I do:
`docker-compose build`
`docker-compose up`

What am I missing?

Comment: Tell compose that you want the container to run detached by doing `docker-compose up -d`.

Comment: @HansKilian That worked. Curious, is there anything I need to change in my existing code to allow me run it without `-d`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the nginx image and copy your content to it. See "Hosting some simple static content" @ https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/:

> a simple Dockerfile can be used to generate a new image that includes the necessary content...

```
FROM nginx
COPY static-html-directory /usr/share/nginx/html
```

> Place this file in the same directory as your directory of content ("static-html-directory"), run `docker build -t some-content-nginx .`, then start your container:

```
$ docker run --name some-nginx -d some-content-nginx
```

Comment: I have updated my question to show what I tried. It gets stuck at `docker-compose up`

Comment: You should literally need only the two lines shown in this answer, four lines if you're going to `COPY` the files individually.  Have you deleted everything aside from the `FROM` and `COPY` lines?  Also check that the second `ports:` number is the standard HTTP port 80.